# Can not authenticate in activecollab using the api

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, activecollab

I am trying to authenticate in `activecollab` to access the projects.

I am trying the following things:

```
api: http://<site url>/api/v1/issue-token

data: {
    "email": "email",
    "password": "password",
    "client_name": "name",
    "client_vendor": "vendor"
}
```

Though I get the message invalid email address, I can log-in with this email and password in my browser. I do not understand the `client vendor`. when I give the client name as the client vendor too, in gives the `invalid email address` message. otherwise, it gives the message `client information missing`.

Comment: Did you get to authenticate and get the issue token. It would be great if you can share the same

Answer (score -1):

I think that client name should be the name of the company, client_vendor should be the name of the app that you are developing and email&password are the same from your active collab account.